# How can I enable TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 cipher suite on Server 2019

Tags: tls1.2

We have a WinServer 2019 machine that needs to make REST requests to a third party using TLS1.2 and Cipher Suite TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256.  From what I've read, this suite should be enabled by default for this OS version, however, when we make the REST call with Schannel logging enabled I see that it's using CipherSuite: 0xC028 which corresponds to TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (CBC vs GCM).  In PowerShell I've tried running *Enable-TlsCiphterSuite -Name "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384" -Position 0* and this does add it to the value at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Cryptography\Configuration\Local\SSL\00010002\Functions.  Though, when I run Get-TlsCipherSuite in PowerShell the TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 suite that was supposedly enabled does not show up.

Is there another place that needs to be changed in order for this cipher suite to be truly enabled?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to achieve this would be downloading a copy of IIS Crypto.

From there you can select the cipher suites tab, enable your chosen cipher and move it to the top as the preferred cipher.

Be aware that some clients may fallback to a weaker cipher if it is available.